# Given a mix of strings, generate an array of only the unique ones.

Tags: php

Test input : dog, dog, cat, cow, dog, horse, cat, dog

valid output : dog, cat, cow, horse

Probably insignificant details : this is for an email function Im writing, where a list of parts are associated with an email address, and I want to 'lump' all the parts that go to the same address together. Using php. I think solving the test case would solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you all, I was not conscious of array_unique(), (although I had used it before... weird how that works).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = implode(', ', array_unique(array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $string))))));
```

From inner to outer

- Split at `,`
- remove any leading and trailing whitespace
- if needed remove any empty string
- return only unique string
- implode with `,` again

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array ( 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'dog' );

$uniqe_array = array_unique ($array);
```

http://php.net/array_unique

Also:

```
$array = array();

$array['dog'] = 1;
$array['cat'] = 2;
$array['dog'] = 3;
```

Result: dog = 3, cat =2. The non unique value will overwrite the previous index.